# how can i use value right way in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello i am a beginner and i want to make a small game by html, c s s and java script the game is that i have a input and button and a div(box) and i want to write in the input a color(red,blue,green and yellow) then click on the button so the background-color div(box) will change

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('input-test'),
  myButton = document.getElementById('button-test'),
  myColor = document.getElementById('color-test');

if (myInput === "blue") {
  myButton.onclick = function() {
    'use strict';
    myColor.classList.add('blue');
  };
} else if (myInput == "red") {
  myButton.onclick = function() {
    'use strict';
    myColor.classList.add('red');
  };
}
```

```css
.in {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.vo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.go {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-test" class="in" type="text" placeholder="Write the color" value="blue">
<button id="button-test" class="vo">click</button>
<div id="color-test" class="go"></div>
```

Comment: No idea why you tagged this C#.

Comment: i dont understand the tag !!!

Comment: You should add tags that are relevant to your question. See [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more info.

Comment: `use strict` should be at the beginning, not in the middle of the code.

Comment: Although it would be better for the `use strict` to be at the top in this small proof-of-concept, it is not actually wrong for it to be at the function scope. It only applies within that function and is useful for gradual transitions in large codebases.

Comment: OP, what is the question then? If something is not working as expected in your code you should mention in your question what did you expect and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  

  const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'black']; //etc
  var myInput = document.getElementById('input-test'),
    myButton = document.getElementById('button-test'),
    myColor = document.getElementById('color-test');
  
    myButton.onclick = function() {
      if(colors.includes(myInput.value)){
        myColor.setAttribute("style", "background-color:" + myInput.value);
      }
    }
```

```css
.in {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.vo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.go {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-test" class="in" type="text" placeholder="Write the color" value="blue">
<button id="button-test" class="vo">click</button>
<div id="color-test" class="go"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the input, and do it when the user clicks.

You also need to remove the other color's class.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('input-test'),
  myButton = document.getElementById('button-test'),
  myColor = document.getElementById('color-test');

myButton.onclick = function() {
  if (myInput.value == "blue") {
    myColor.classList.add('blue');
    myColor.classList.remove('red');
  } else if (myInput.value == "red") {
    myColor.classList.add('red');
    myColor.classList.remove('blue');
  };
}
```

```css
.in {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.vo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.go {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-test" class="in" type="text" placeholder="Write the color" value="blue">
<button id="button-test" class="vo">click</button>
<div id="color-test" class="go"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much but wen i run the code i found blue is already written in the input , i want the place holder appear in the input

Comment: Then don't write `value="blue"` in the input. That's the initial value.